# Throwing custom exception in servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception, servlets, servlet-3.0

I want to throw a custom `exception`, somewhat like the following, from a servlet whenever some specific problem occurs.

```
public class CustomException extends Throwable {

    private String[] errArray;

    public CustomException(String[] errArray){
        this.errArray = errArray;
    }

    public String[] getErrors(){
        return errArray;
    }

}
```

And then when this exception is thrown I want to redirect the user to a specific error page.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>com.example.CustomException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Here is the error page, I want to use the exception implicit object.

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="my" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>

<my:head title="Error"></my:head>
<body>
    <% String errArray = exception.getErrors(); %>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the problem occurs when I go to add `CustomException` in `throws` declaration of the servlet's `doGet` method. I get the following error:

```
Exception CustomException is not compatible with throws clause in HttpServlet.doGet(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
```

Now how can I overcome the problem? Is it even possible to custom exception like this & forward to error page when It is thrown? Or is there any other way?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpServlet` class `doGet` throws `ServletException` as declared below:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,
                 HttpServletResponse resp)
          throws ServletException,
                 java.io.IOException
```

Please make your `CustomException` to extend `ServletException` to comply with the method specification.

EDIT: In your error.jsp, get the errors as:

```
<% String[] errArray = null; 
  if(exception instanceof CustomException) {
     errArray = (CustomException)exception.getErrors();
  } 
%>
```

**Please note:** It returns `String[]`

Comment: Question, couldn't you instead extend `RuntimeException` since they do not have to be caught or declared in the signature?

Comment: @jschoen: Certainly you can, but I prefer to avoid them in scenarios like this where some post behavior is expected based on the exception similar to `doGet` itself which throws `ServletExcetion` deliberately.

Comment: just checked. It doesn't redirect to the error page. Am I missing something?

Comment: well, I think It actually redirects, but shows up this problem now:
`An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jsp/errorPage.jsp
The method getErrors() is undefined for the type Throwable`

Comment: @sha404: print exception.getClass().getName() to check which exception are you getting there? I think, you need to do typecasting there as: <% `String errArray = (CustomException)exception.getErrors(); %>`

Comment: @YogendraSingh I have not done anything with jsp in a long time, but could you simply to an `instance of` check to your exception type, and if it matches cast it to get what you want?

Comment: @jschoen Updating the answer with this: <% String[] errArray = null; if(exception instanceof CustomException) {errArray = (CustomException)exception.getErrors();} %>